# ¿Cómo validar con jQuery unos input creados con un for?

Tags: php, html, jquery, formularios, jquery-validate

Buenas tardes tengo un formulario que crea unos *inputs* dependiendo de un número que otorga el cliente y necesito validar que estos *inputs* no este vacíos.

Para validar los campos de otros formularios que he hecho uso `jqueryvalidator`.

Como en este ejemplo:

```
$(form).validate({
        rules: {
            txt_guia0: {required: true},
            txt_placas: {required: true},
        },
        messages: {
            txt_guia0: {required: " * Ingrese el codigo de barras"},
            txt_placas: {required: " * Ingrese el número de placas"}
        }
    });
```

Pero ahora mi problema es que los *id* son dinámicos.
Intenté con un contador y un *for* pero no me deja la sintaxis de *jQuery*.

**¿Alguien sabe como puedo resolver esto o con que otro método puedo hacer que los *imput* sean obligatorios?**

Mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form id="frmVehiculo" name="frmVehiculo" action="/" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Datos del Ajuste de Posición</legend>
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <?php

                        for ($index = 0; $index < $num; $index++) {

                            if ($index==0) {
                                echo'<tr class="spaceUnder">';
                                echo"<td><label>Folio del avance: ".$id_avance."</label>";
                                echo' </tr>';
                                echo' <tr>';
                                 echo"<label>Número de tarimas: ".$num."</label></td>";
                                echo' </tr>';
                            }
                            echo'<tr class="spaceUnder">';
                            echo"<td><label id=label".$index.">".$etiquetas_array[$index]."</label> <input type='text' id='txt_guia".$index."' name='txt_guia".$index."' value='' onchange='Validar(".$index.");' required></td>";
                            echo' </tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    <label></label>
                    </table>
                    </fieldset>
                    <?php
                    echo '<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="' . $Id_produccion . '" />';
                 echo '<input type="hidden" id="numta" name="numta" value="' . $num . '" />';
                 echo '<input type="hidden" id="numserie" name="numserie" value="' . $id_tarima2 . '" />';
                 echo '<input type="hidden" id="avance" name="avance" value="' . $id_avance . '" />';
    ?>
                <input type="button" class="boton" value="Guardar" id="guardar" />
                <input type="button" class="boton" value="Cancelar" onclick="cambiarContenidos('Aceptacion/lista_aceptacion_pt.php', 4, 91, '');return false;"/>                         
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo por que estás usando ID's dinámicos, podrías explotar más la información si te adentraras en las bondades de HTML5. En fin, lo que puedes hacer es asignarle una clase a ese input yo le puse `valida` y tu input quedaría así

```
<input type='text' id='txt_guia".$index."' 
name='txt_guia".$index."' value='' class="valida"
onchange='Validar(".$index.");' required>
```

Ahora en tu script de reglas puedes asignar una regla para un elemento con una cierta clase en específico, sin necesidad de pasar todo el form, pero tienes que ciclarlo, de lo contrario solo afectará uno

```
$('.valida').each( function(){
  $(this).rules('add', {
     required: true
     // aqui más reglas
  });
});
```

Eso debería funcionar

Comment: me sale este error TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined

Comment: Creo que eso es parte de tu código o de la versión de jquery que usas... Tienes la 3.X +?